# Email composer in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is it Possible to show Standard Email Composer in Salesforce Lightning/Lightning Component.

Does anyone has implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This has been introduced in Winter 23 release.

See link :
[Access the Email Composer from Custom Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_email_composer_access.htm&type=5&release=240)